# How to have dotnet restore search all repositories?

Tags: .net, nuget

I am trying to do a `dotnet restore` on a simple project that has two repos, a private one and the public nuget one.

The private one has one package that has a bunch of dependencies that are in the public nuget repo, not the private.

What is happening though is when I do restore, it'll try to restore all of the private repo's package dependencies only from the private repo, and not try to search the public repo.

Is this by design or am I missing something?

```
Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host

  Version  : 1.1.0
  Build    : 928f77c4bc3f49d892459992fb6e1d5542cb5e86


λ  dotnet --version
1.0.1
```